# Очерёдность вызова деструктора

Tags: c++

Имеем класс D унаследованного от класса B , а в классе D есть данные класса M. Вопрос при вызове деструктора класса D порядок будет  M D B ?

Comment: Вы ведь можете это проверить сами просто написав пример с деструкторами  (╯_╰)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

это легко проверить:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class M{
public:
    ~M(){ cout << "M" << endl; }
};

class B{
public:
    ~B(){ cout << "B" << endl; }
};

class D : public B{
public:
    ~D(){ cout << "D" << endl; }
    M m;
};

int main(){
    D * d = new D;
    delete(d);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 18):

Гарантирован следующий порядок:

- Сначала отрабатывает код деструктора самого класса (`D`).
- Затем вызываются деструкторы подобъектов самого класса (`M`). При этом `M` должен быть именно подобъектом, указатель не катит.

  - Порядок уничтожения подобъектов противоположен порядку их объявления в классе.
- Затем вызываются деструкторы *невиртуальных* базовых классов (`B`). Для них продолжается эта же история, рекурсивно вниз.

  - Порядок уничтожения базовых объектов противоположен порядку их объявления в списке наследования.
- Затем вызываются деструкторы всех виртуальных базовых классов.

  - Порядок вызова противоположен порядку виртуальных конструкторов: обходится дерево базовых классов, составляется список виртуальных базовых классов (игнорируя дубликаты), и в обратном порядке вызываются деструкторы.

---

Ссылки на официальный C++ FAQ:

1. [When I write a destructor, do I need to explicitly call the destructors for my member objects?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#calling-member-dtors)
2. [When I write a derived class’s destructor, do I need to explicitly call the destructor for my base class?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#calling-base-dtor)
3. [What is the exact order of destructors in a multiple and/or virtual inheritance situation?](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/multiple-inheritance#mi-vi-dtor-order)

Comment: обалдеть, существует официальный C++ FAQ. Не знал

Comment: По поводу деструкторов базовых классов: я бы вообще убрал этот пункт, ну или уже распишите полностью, с учётом виртуального наследования

Comment: @ixSci: Про деструктор базового класса в исходном вопросе, поэтому удалить не получится. Добавил про виртуальное наследование.

Comment: @ixSci раньше он был [здесь](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/) но потом переехал на isocpp.org.

Answer (score 5):

Деструкторы вызываются в обратном порядке относительно конструкторов.

Деструкторы членов класса будут вызваны в обратном порядке относительно их инициализации после выполнения тела деструктора класса.

Таким образом, порядок будет: `D M B`.

Немного из стандарта:

> After executing the body of the destructor and destroying any
>   automatic objects allocated within the body, a destructor for class X
>   calls the destructors for X’s direct non-variant non-static data
>   members, the destructors for X’s direct base classes and, if X is the
>   type of the most derived class (12.6.2), its destructor calls the
>   destructors for X’s virtual base classes. All destructors are called
>   as if they were referenced with a qualified name, that is, ignoring
>   any possible virtual overriding destructors in more derived classes.
>   Bases and members are destroyed in the reverse order of the completion
>   of their constructor (see 12.6.2). A return statement (6.6.3) in a
>   destructor might not directly return to the caller; before
>   transferring control to the caller, the destructors for the members
>   and bases are called. Destructors for elements of an array are called
>   in reverse order of their construction (see 12.6).